# Checksum error while provisioning Android with QR Code

Tags: android, qr-code, provisioning

I am trying to implement the provisioning of a device using the QR Code method as described here [Provisioning using QR Code](https://developers.google.com/android/work/prov-devices#qr_code_method)

I managed to get the apk signature checksum using this command

`apksigner verify -print-certs [path to the apk] | grep -Po "(?<=SHA-256 digest:) .*" | xxd -r -p | openssl base64 | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '='`

Also because I wanted to be sure that the checksum was correct I used the above command to the apk from the example [Down Box QR Code](http://down-box.appspot.com/qr/nQB0tw7b) and the checksum was correct.

As the tutorial points:

1. to a factory reset device I tap 6 times in the welcome screen.
2. Then the device downloads a qrcode app.
3. Using this app I scan the QR code that I've created and then I am asked to encrypt the device.
4. After the device's encryption the device restarts and tries to download my admin app. At that point I get the error dialog saying "Ooops! Couldn't use the admin app due to a checksum error. Contact your IT department".

I am quite sure that the checksum is correct, has anybody figured what might the problem be?

** UPDATE **

Found what was causing the problem. The apk should not be uploaded in google drive cause it is not downloadable immediately. If there is no other way follow this tutorial [Google Drive direct link](https://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/)

Also the url to the apk should not be very long. If you shorten it (there are many sites doing) everything works ok.

Comment: How long is very long or the APK url?

Comment: I also encounter this misleading checksum error and suspect that the real root cause may be related to the length of the APK download URL string as specified in android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION. Do you know if there is a limit to this string length?